# Assign each point with it's nearest center in Matlab

Tags: matlab, distance

I have  100 points that are saved in a  matrix and 3 centers in another matrix. I want to assign each point with the nearest center in Matlab and create 3 groups with each center.

For Example:

```
centers = [1,12];
points = [2,3,4,15,18,20];
```

I want to get 2 groups as output:

```
group1 = [1,2,3,4];
group2 = [12,15,18,20];
```

Both points and centers have same  dimension and distance is Euclidean.Every row represents a point.

Is there a function in Matlab that does this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to compute the distance of each point to each center, then find which center is closest to each point. In 1D this is quite simple:

```matlab
centers = [1,12];
points = [2,3,4,15,18,20];
dist = abs(points - centers.');  % we use implicit singleton expansion here
[~,group] = min(dist,[],1);      % returns group = [1,1,1,2,2,2]
```

Note that `dist` is a 2D matrix. `dist(i,j)` is the distance of `centers(i)` to `points(j)`. The output, `group`, indicates, for each point, which of the centers is nearest.

In 2 or more dimensions this is slightly more complex, because `centers` and `points` are 2D matrices, we need an intermediate 3D array to compute Euclidean distances:

```matlab
centers = [0,1,1,0;...
           0,0,1,1];          % centers(:,i) is the coordinates for center i
points = rand(2,12);          % 12 points in 2D
dist = reshape(points,2,1,[]) - centers; % this is a 3D array
dist = sqrt(sum(dist.^2,1));  % in very new versions of MATLAB do vecnorm(dist,2,1)
dist = squeeze(dist);         % removes the first dimension
[~,group] = min(dist,[],1);
```

The code above assumes each column of `points` and `centers` is a coordinate. If the orientation of the matrices is the other way around, with each row a coordinate, the code would look like this:

```matlab
centers = [0,0;1,0;1,1;0,1];  % centers(i,:) is the coordinates for center i
points = rand(12,2);          % 12 points in 2D
dist = reshape(points,1,[],2) - reshape(centers,[],1,2);
dist = sqrt(sum(dist.^2,3));  % in very new versions of MATLAB do vecnorm(dist,2,3)
[~,group] = min(dist,[],1);
```

Comment: I have a problem with points > 1D, both centers and points with the same D. I tried this centers = [4,3;1,7] points =[4,3;8,6] output group= 2 2  that means both point in the group 2a s I think it's not correct

Comment: @pua: maybe you’re looking at the arrays the wrong way around. In your example you have centers (4,1) and (3,7). Each columns is a coordinate. Both points, (4,8) and (3,6) are closest to the second center.

Comment: Each row represents a point, In my example not a column. If I want to modify it, do I need to reshape the matrix?

Comment: @Pua: I have updated the answer. Your question shows a 1D example. Next time, show an example that represents your problem better, I could have given you the correct solution right away.